# NodeJS error on latest CiviBuild

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

Encountering the following npm related issue on using the latest buildkit. Any suggestions? NPM is already at latest.

If someone has a working buildkit they could tell me which version of npm they're on that'd be great.

Thanks.

vagrant@civi:~$ ~/buildkit/bin/civibuild create "4719" --admin-pass "password" --civi-ver "4.7.19-rc" --type "drupal-demo" --url "http://4719:7979" --force
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.25
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:298
        [this, (next) => { computeMetadata(this.idealTree); next() }],
                       ^
npm ERR! Unexpected token >

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2017-06-04T20_40_46_477Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to upgrade your nodejs version - https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: This is the correct answer.  See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/issues/315.